# read json output in php

Tags: php, json

how to read below json data in php?
i have "**$json = json_decode($data,true);** and 
i tryied "**$json->{'screenShareCode'};**" but  is is giving me an error? :(

```
    array(5) {
      ["screenShareCode"]=>
      string(9) "887874819"
      ["appletHtml"]=>
      string(668) ""
      ["presenterParams"]=>
      string(396) "aUsEdyygd6Yi5SqaJss0="
      ["viewerUrl"]=>
      string(65) "http://api.screenleap.com/v2/viewer/814222219?accountid=myid"
      ["origin"]=>
      string(3) "API"
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your output is regular array not JSON, so you access it as regular PHP array:

```
$x = $array['screenShareCode']
```

Answer (score 1):

The output you are showing is not json. It seems to be a [print_r](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php)'ed array.

See http://json.org/example

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for json_encode (https://www.php.net/json_encode)

Answer (score 0):

What you posted is an array, not an object. Because you passed `json_decode` a second parameter of `true`, it responded with an associative array instead of an object.

To access a property of an associative array, you can do something like `$json['screenShareCode']`.